# What is the best practice to handle friendly urls in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, seo, friendly-url

We have an online-shop.

We can have any friendly urls 
as for separate models like products or categories (/iphone-6-white = /iphones/23) 
as for custom filter urls like (/cool-flashes = /flash?cap=32gb&col=white)

What is the best practice to handle all urls?

IMHO we should create a table where we should store two cols (urlFrom and RedirectUrl). But redirect is not good way for us because we do not want a redirect, we just want to show appropriate content under the urlFrom.

I want to store it in a single table to make just one request to DB to find out whether we have the url or not.

Comment: we should not also forget that its important to make a convinient tool to parse redirectUrls.
if we catch from /blabla that we should show /categories?col=black&size=2  how we will handle that?

Comment: Use slugs. https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Answer (score 0):

You can create submit your form in array such as `search[name]`, `search[price][form]` and create your custom Middleware that will checks request contain of `search[]` build url and after that redirect to this page.

Of course after that you must create route for those page, like:

```
Route::get('/search/{searchName?}/{searchPriceFrom?}', 'ProductsController@search');
```

Where your `RoutesServiceProvoider` will look like this:

```
Route::bind('searchName', function($term) {
    // your DB query and checks...
});
```